# C programming Loops need explanation please

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

Which one of these `for` loop statements executes its body exactly three times?

1. `for (i=1; i<4; i++) { /* body */ }`
2. `for (i=0; i<=3; i++) { /* body */ }`

I've got the correct answer which is (1) but I don't know why (2) is incorrect.

Comment: Maybe you should solve your own homework. It is a very expensive knowledge, if you learn things such like, you will be rich after you graduate.

Comment: 2. example iterations: `0->1->2->3 = 4 iterations` since 3 <= 3 is ture!

Comment: 1) {i | 1,2,3} 2){i | 0,1,2,3}

Comment: Hint: place a print statement inside

Comment: You have got to be kidding.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized and doesn't fit well into the Stack Exchange model.

Comment: Besides: You're saying that you don't know why (2) is incorrect... But do you know why (1) is correct?

Comment: You really should learn how to [debug loops](http://cis.poly.edu/cs1114/mings-websites/ch02/debug.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one. The reason is that it will loop when `i` is 1,2 and 3 and will stop when `i` is 4 as `i<4` becomes false thus looping 3 times.

The second one is not right as it will loop 4 times,namely when `i` is 0,1,2,3 and will stop when `i` is 4 as `i<=3` becomes false.

Comment: I think we shouldn't do the homework for other people...

Comment: @Rizier123 i'm trying to learn how it works, its not homework

Comment: @TarunPatel Then I advise you personally to read more about `c` or try at least a few more times before you ask a question

Answer (score 1):

All is very simple if to take into account that condition

```
i <= 3
```

is equivalent to condition

```
i < 4
```

So if in the second loop to substitute condition `i <= 3` for equivalent condition `i < 4` then the loop

```
2.for (i=0; i <= 3; i++) { /* body */ }
```

can be rewritten like

```
2.for (i=0; i < 4; i++) { /* body */ }
```

Now compare it with the first loop

```
1.for (i=1; i < 4; i++) { /* body */ }

2.for (i=0; i < 4; i++) { /* body */ }
```

As it is seen the first loop starts from i = 1 while the second loop starts from i = 0. So the second loop has one iteration more than the first loop.  As the first loop has 3 iterations as you said yourself then the second loop has four iterations.:)

Answer (score 0):

The second loop executes four times:  once each for i = 0, 1, 2, and 3.  The first executes three times, once each for i = 1, 2, and 3.  The important fact here is that the iterated variable in the first loop initializes to 1, but the iterated variable in the second loop initializes to 0.

Answer (score 0):

In number 2 it doesn't stop until i becomes equal to 4. The loop keeps going when i hits 3 because i equal to 3 is one of the commands for it to keep going.

Answer (score 0):

For 1:

The limit of i is from 1 to less than 4, means the ending value is 3. (As i is an integer, the best possible value less than 4 is 3).

So:

`i=1, i=2, i=3` (The loop is executed three times)

Similarly for 2 :

The limit for i is from 0 to less than equal to 3, means the ending value is 3.

So:

`i=0,i=1,i=2,i=3` (The loop is executed four times)